# Access RDS from T2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I have an already existing RDS instance created an year ago.

I recently created an EC2 instance of type t2. I am unable to access the RDS instance from t2 instance.

Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Did you check the DB security group? Does the DB security group authorize access from your EC2 instance?

Comment: thanks. I resolved it myself. you are correct, the issue was with SG only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the DB security group

The DB security group must authorize access from the EC2 instance (recommended to give permission to the EC2 security group).